# Generate variables with loop over pairs of variables

Tags: stata

I have data on quantities and Values for a set of countries, and currently the variable names are **Q_US V_US Q_UK V_UK Q_France V_France** and in that order: Quantity_country Value_country, etc.

For each country (US, UK, France, etc.) I want to generate a new variable that gives me the unit value. Manually I would create them as

```
gen unit_US = V_US/Q_US
gen unit_UK = V_UK/Q_UK
gen unit_France = V_France/Q_France
```

But I have 100+ countries, and it would be great to do this in a loop if possible.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's get a list of all the countries as you have used them in variable names.

```
unab where : V_* 
local where " `where'" 
local where : subinstr local where " V_" " ", all
```

The additional space is designed to ensure that the text removed is just the prefix `V_` at the start of variable names. For another example of using `unab`, see [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/index.html).

Check it worked:

```
display "`where'"
```

Now loop:

```
foreach c of local where { 
    gen unit_`c' = V_`c'/Q_`c' 
}
```

I'd also consider `reshape long`.